# A construction using *so*

Tags: expressions

How would you rewrite the following sentence more properly?

> The sea is blue and the sky also.

I know that there is a specific construction using *so*, but in fact I never used it...

Comment: OP's original sounds terrible to me ([In British English it (the word "**also**") is not usually used at the end of a sentence.](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/also)) But maybe it's more acceptable to Anericans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sea is blue and so is the sky

Comment: Thank you, it is what I had in mind. Otherwise, is the sentence above still correct?

Comment: If you mean your original sentence, yes